# Unity C# combining two areas each represented by a vector

Tags: unity, c#, vector

have two areas, which are both given in there bounds.size. Now the z-axis doesnt matter for me, since im working in 2D. I want to add these vectors so i have a vector, which represents the jointed area. Simply adding these vectors the normal way does not work. The way the area looks in the end is not important, its just important that the size is the same as, both areas combined.

I have the bounds.size of two polygoncolliders and i want to get a value that represents the bounds.size of the two polygoncolliders combined

https://i.stack.imgur.com/avmcl.png

area 1 and area 2

Edit: it has to work in this scenario also:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Not sure what you're asking about vectors. Do you just want to store their width and height in a vector2?

Comment: i Want to get the bounds.size of the two areas combined

Comment: You just want the value of the area? That's just the area of the first plus the area of the second. (bounds1.size.x*bounds1.size.y)+(bounds2.size.x*bounds2.size.y).

Comment: Here are [three different things you might mean by "combining two areas"](https://imgur.com/a/7BQ3t). Which one do you actually want? Or, if it's none of the above, please provide an example that explicitly shows the outcome you're looking for.

Comment: By the way, [cross posting between GameDev and SO is discouraged](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263/cross-posting-programming-questions-on-stackoverflow-and-gamedev-stackexchange). ([Other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47676324/unity-c-adding-two-areas-represented-by-two-vectors))

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as Draco18s notes, it is a [cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47676324/unity-c-adding-two-areas-represented-by-two-vectors). Please ask questions on only one exchange at a time.

Answer (score 2):

> I have the bounds.size of two polygoncolliders

```
Bounds CombineBounds(Bounds a, Bounds b) {
    // Grow a copy of the first Bounds to include
    // the min & max points of the second Bounds.
    a.Encapsulate(b.min);
    a.Encapsulate(b.max);
    return a;
}
```

You can check the returned `Bounds` object's `size` property to get the total size of the combined bounds.

Comment: that's a neat trick.

Comment: what do you mean by growing a copy of the first bounds?

Comment: I mean that we copy the first Bounds struct (structs in C# are passed by value by default, not by reference, so we're not modifying the original bounds sent by the caller), then extend it to the left, right, top, and/or bottom as needed so that it includes both its original rectangle and the rectangle represented by the second bounds struct.

Comment: but  it is not working in the scenario i added to my question, right?

Comment: You tell me. What's the outcome you want in this situation? The size of the entire rectangle that includes both the red and blue shapes and the space between them? Or the length of each axis's coloured portions, ignoring the space between them?

Comment: i just want the size of the two coloured rectangles combined, without the empty space.

Comment: ok, i found a way how to do it, thanks alot for taking your time helping me anyways :)

Comment: Make sure you edit your question to clarify what you originally wanted. Then you can post your own answer to share your solution with other users.

Answer (score 0):

Credits for this answer go to Flater: https://stackoverflow.com/users/952296/flater

As there are nigh infinite possibilities otherwise, I'm going to limit myself to results where x = y, for the simple reason that you don't end up with silly vectors like (0.5,80000) but rather a more balanced (200,200).

This isn't all that hard when you look at it algebraically:

float result_area = first_area + second_area;

Calculating the area is easy:

float area = myVector.X * myVector.Y;

Thus rendering the sum of the areas also easy:

float result_area = myFirstVector.X * myFirstVector.Y + mySecondVector.X * mySecondVector.Y;

For the sake of example, let's say first_area = 50 and second_area = 350, thus resulting in result_area = 400;

Since we are limited to results where x = y, the result is the square root of the area:

float theSquareRoot = Math.Sqrt(result_area);
myResultVector.X = theSquareRoot;
myResultVector.Y = theSquareRoot;

As I said, there are many other possible result vectors. For other cases, you're either going to have to define a given ratio (e.g. a ratio of 1 : 4 would give you (10,40) for the same example), but the calculation is a bit harder and you mentioned that you don't care about the exact shape anyway.

You could also just make a vector where X = result_area and Y = 1 (or vice versa), without having to calculate a square root.

Note that you've overengineered it. The area of an object is a onedimensional value (a number); yet you're expressing it using a twodimensional value (a number pair) to represent them.
Since you don't care about particular X/Y values, only what their product is, I would suggest you avoid vectors where possible, so you don't make it unnecessarily complicated.